# Joint Density example

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be positive dependent random variables with finite means s.t $(X,Y)\sim f_{X,Y}$. I want to find examples of the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$  s.t $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)\not=f_{X,Y}(y,x)$$
And $$\int e^{tx}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx=h(t,y),\ \int e^{ty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dy=h(t,x), \ \forall t\in (-\infty,b)$$
Is it possible to construct such examples?

Comment: In your second equation LHS is a function of $t$ and $y$ and RHS is a function of $t$ and $x$ .

Comment: yes. They are the same function.